# Same vega-lite spec produces different PNG output on different hosts

Tags: vega-lite

I have this vega-lite spec which I convert to a png using `vl2png`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "encoding": {
    "x": { "field": "category", "type": "nominal" },
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Foo"}
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "A", "Foo": 0.1},
      {"category": "B", "Foo": 0.7},
      {"category": "C", "Foo": 0.6}
    ]
  }
}
```

I try the same on two different boxes. Both running Ubuntu 22.04 with node 18.5.0, vega-lite 5.6.0, vega 5.22.1, canvas 2.11.0.

On the first, I get this PNG which looks right:

[image: Good looking Bar & Point chart]

On the second I get this PNG which has all the bars squished to a line:

[image: Bad looking Bar & Point chart]

Any idea what's happening here? Is there anything else I should look at to determine where the problem could be?

I see the same when converting to svg as well.

Additionally it looks as though the X & Y axis labels are no longer centered.

Furthermore, if I convert the vega-lite spec to a vega spec, both boxes generate the exact same vega spec, but calling vg2png on that spec also produces different PNGs.